# Php access a static method on class

Tags: php, oop, parameter-passing, multilingual

First all i'm new on OOP. Sorry if this is a noob question.

I'm building a multilanguage web site. I'm fetching database values with languga iso's. For eg: `index.php?lang=en` if language value is set with $_GET parameter, mysql brings only en values in database. The problem is with my LanguageController.

```
// LanguageController Class
class LanguageController {
    public $lang = "en";
    public function __construct() {
        return true;    
    }
    public static function detectLang() {
        $lang = 'en';
        ob_start();
        session_start();
        if(isset($_GET["lang"])) {
            $lang= $_GET["lang"];
            $_SESSION["lang"] = $lang;
            setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
        }
        else {
            $lang = 'en';
            $_SESSION["lang"] = $lang;
            setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to pass default $lang parameter for eg 'en'. 
If client change language to 'fr', i must start a session. And mysql brings 'fr' language values.
How can i pass my `$lang` parameter on my `detectLang()` method.

I tried `var_dump(LanguageController::detectLang())`
It's coming `NULL`.

Any help greatly appricated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there's no `return` statement in a function - returned value is `NULL`. Obviously your `detectLang` function works and the `isset($_GET["lang"])` condition is `true`, in this case the returned value is `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you so much. i added `return $lang` value and it returns `string 'en' (length=2)`

Answer (score -1):

In static methods you can only reference to static attributes. In simple words, the $lang needs to be static as well i.e.

```
public static var $lang = "en";
```